# List all the preview diffs in phabricator

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

Is there a way to list out all the preview diffs in Phabricator? 
That is, I created a diff using `arc diff --preview`, but have lost track of the diff URL and have lost the original local git commits that went with it. I'd like to regenerate them using `arc patch --diff`, but I don't know the diff number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arc diff preview is not intended for storing commits for later. Just create a revision and don't assign anyone it's the exact same thing.

You can't do anything through the UI to recover these as this was never the intention of --preview. If you have access to the database you can go into the *_user.user find your user phid then go into the *_differential.differential_diff table and select all users with this PHID. Or just have your DBA run this for you.

```
SELECT * 
FROM phabricator_differential.differential_diff 
WHERE authorPhid 
IN (
    SELECT phid 
    FROM phabricator_user.user 
    WHERE username = 'Kirby'
   )
AND revisionID IS NULL;
```

From the id column in this list you can access your diffs at the following url. `https://phabricator.com/differential/diff/{id}/`.

This is a very old ticket upstream that would likely be part of adding better diff support to the UI https://secure.phabricator.com/T1084. I haven't seen much interest in this ever though so i don't imagine it will be supported in the next year unless your company or yourself is willing to pay them to make it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Phabricator and to the project using it. Generating a review isn't an option because on our project you shall specify a reviewer. I was also told that this project doesn't want to push local branches to the remote git. But, as far as I can tell, for the purpose of backing up my work, that is the only option

Comment: You could look into using the `--plan-changes` flag when running arc diff. I don't currently know of anyway to force someone from not not adding a reviewer unless they have custom herald rules setup which add them on every diff. However using --plan-changes will make sure that people listed on review are not being bugged about it.

Comment: oh, yeah. That's better! Thanks